# lua + папки "на русском"

Tags: lua, locale

Как реализовать корректную работу с папками на русском языке в виндовс 
os.setlocale('ISO-8859-5'), os.setlocale("Russian_Russia.1251") и пр. к желаемому результату не привели...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вставил предложенный Вами код, результат прежний:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ОС: WIN 7, Луа - бинарник LuaForWindows (lua 5.1).

Попробовал в консоли, тот же результат...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте для обхода каталогов использовать внешнюю библиотеку [ex](http://lua-users.org/wiki/ExtensionProposal)
и функцию перекодирования 1251->866:

```
require 'ex'

--[[
1251: А  - Я а - п  192 - 239
866:   А  - Я а - п  128 - 175
1251: р-я  240 - 255
866:   р-я  224 - 239
1251: Ё- 168 ё - 184
866:   Ё- 240 ё - 241
]]
local function from1251_to866(s)
    local    str = ''
    for i=1, string.len(s) do
        local byte = s:byte(i)
        local b = byte
        if (byte >= 192 and byte <= 239) then  
                 b =  byte-64       
        elseif  (byte >= 240 and byte <= 255 ) then
                 b = byte-16
        elseif byte == 168 then b=240 --Ё
        elseif byte == 184 then b=241 --ё
        end
        str = str .. string.char(b)
    end
    return str  
end
local function CheckDir(curpath,d)
     local fullname = (curpath.."\\"..d.name):gsub("\\$","")
     print(from1251_to866(fullname))
      for entry in os.dir(fullname) do
          if entry["type"]=="directory" then  CheckDir(fullname, entry)    end
          if entry["type"]=="file" then

                 print( from1251_to866(fullname .."\\" ..entry.name) )
          end
       end  
end
-- тестируем :
    local s = [[АБВГДЕЁЖЗИКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ абвгдеёжзиклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя 0123456789 qwertyQWERTY !@#$%^&*()_+]]

print(from1251_to866(s) )


local pathname = os.currentdir()
local init = { ["type"]="directory", name="" }
CheckDir( pathname, init )
```

вывод в консоли с кодировкой 866 (режим DOS):

```
АБВГДЕЁЖЗИКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ абвгдеёжзиклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя 0123456789 qwertyQWERTY !@#$%^&*()_+
d:\Projects\Lua\tmp
d:\Projects\Lua\tmp\include2
d:\Projects\Lua\tmp\test.lua
d:\Projects\Lua\tmp\test.luac
d:\Projects\Lua\tmp\test2.lua
d:\Projects\Lua\tmp\test2.luac
d:\Projects\Lua\tmp\папка на русском
d:\Projects\Lua\tmp\папка на русском\inc_inc
d:\Projects\Lua\tmp\папка на русском\inc_inc\meta.lua
d:\Projects\Lua\tmp\папка на русском\meta.lua
```

Comment: В какой версии Lua эта библиотека встроена?

Comment: у меня ex.dll в  5.1 лежит в \clibs можно взять [вот тут dll](https://github.com/rjpcomputing/luaforwindows/tree/master/files/clibs) . Еще ссылки: [сам проект](http://lua-users.org/wiki/ExtensionProposal) и [GitHub](https://github.com/luaforge/lua-ex)

Comment: @zed забыл адресовать комментарий выше

Comment: Ну так это значит что он не встроен. Это просто некий внешний модуль.

Comment: @mike-v попробовал приедложенный Вами вариант, к сожалению результат прежний, скриншот выше

Comment: @Vitaliy_123 ну так там кодировка 866 скорее всего у вас в Far.  Lua выводит в 1251, чтобы просматривать в 1251 выполните команду chcp 1251 [как на скриншоте](http://i.imgur.com/3Qubwxz.png)

Comment: @mile-v Результат тот-же отрицательный (3-й скрин). Команду chcp 1251 перед этим выполнял.

Comment: @ mike-v в консоле (cmd) нормально отображается только chcp 866, но это ДОС-кодировка, а нужно русская 1251. Приложение планируется запускать на некотором количестве компьютеров...

Comment: @Vitaliy_123 Вы в одном вопросе пытаетесь решить сразу 2 проблемы: 1) работа с файловой системой; 2) работа с консолью. В рамках SO так не принято. Для работы с ФС вам порекомендовали модуль `ex` - это является решением вашей первой проблемы. Чтобы решить вторую проблему, создайте новый вопрос. И да, метод с `chcp` работает, но вы его, судя по всему, неправильно используете.

Comment: @MikeV. Отредактируйте пожалуйста ваш ответ и уберите упоминание о том, что модуль `ex` является встроенным. Это ошибочное утверждение.

Comment: пробуйте, добавил функцию перекодировки 1251->866 @zed - поправил про ex

Comment: @MikeV. Спасибо работает, правда print(from1251_to866(s) ) выводит ерунду, но папки на русском отображает верно. Ваш первый вариант тоже работает если запускать через батник:chcp 1251
lua otvet_rus_lua.lua
pause
Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу . . .

Comment: @zed   Поиск натолкнул на следующее: chcp 1251 корректно работает если в свойствах консоли стоит шрифт Lucida Console если нет, то увы. Через батник (cм. выше) это решается но это костыль, хотя имеет право на существование...

Comment: @Vitaliy_123 ну печать строки s у вас ерунду выдает потому что кодировка самого скрипта видимо не 1251, что подсунешь, то и получишь :-)

Comment: @MikeV. Получилось с точностью до наоборот, "s" выводит правильно, а  программа крашится на os.currentdir() --(nil value). Главное что получилось то что я хотел, завтра попробую на целевой машине перепроверить, еще раз спасибо за потраченное время.

Answer (score 2):

Тестовый пример:

```
local lfs = require("lfs")

local function print_dir()      
  for f in lfs.dir("b:\\") do
    print(f)
  end
end

print("Current locale: " .. os.setlocale(nil, "ctype"))
os.execute("chcp")
print("Кракозябры")
print_dir()

os.setlocale("", "ctype")
print("Current locale: " .. os.setlocale(nil, "ctype"))
os.execute("chcp")
print("Нормальный текст")
print_dir()
```

Если его сохранить в файл с кодировкой Win-1251 и выполнить в консоли, то получится вот это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно заметить, после того, как мы указали Lua, с какой локалью мы имеем дело (т.е. какая кодировка файла с сорцами и, соответственно, в какой кодировке у нас строки), функция `print` сделала некоторую "подкапотную" работу и вывод в консоль получился в нужной кодировке. Магия заключается в следующем:

- если локаль не задана (т.е. используется дефолтная "C"-локаль), то текст выводится на экран как есть. И поскольку у файла кодировка 1251, то именно в ней и выводится.
- если локаль задана, то текст из указанной локали переводится в текущую локаль консоли (т.е. из 1251 в 866).

Что касается ZeroBrainStudio, то там сорцы надо конвертировать в UTF-8, поскольку она весь ввод/вывод воспринимает как UTF-8. Но, к примеру, модуль `lfs` отдаёт строки в системной кодировке (1251) и чтобы получить читаемый вывод в консоли ZeroBrainStudio, строки нужно вручную конвертировать из 1251 в UTF-8 при помощи каких-то внешних библиотек.

Comment: Благодарю за развернутый ответ. На данный момент получены исчерпывающие ответы.